# Drupal, getting list of nodes gives 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have added RESTful Web Service module for my Drupal application.

I have added all permissions for anonymous users for RESTful Web Service.

I can access to specific nodes when I write something like this.

```
example.com/node/<id_of_node>.json
```

However, When I try to access to list of nodes like this:

```
example.com/node.json
```

It gives to me `403 Forbidden` error.

Why this is happening?

Comment: Don't you have some log about the 403?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error code `403 Forbidden` clearly suggests the issue is related with permissions.

If you have set the permissions correctly and there is no other modules for managing access to nodes it should have worked.

[image]

I recommend checking out enabled modules for `Content Access Control`.

Also you may want to check the status report for `Node Access Permissions`, rebuilding the permissions may resolve the issue you are having.

[image]

Comment: I have added this permission and then recreated permissions in status report. This problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you have checked your permissions (each resource is protected with a RESTWS permission that can be configured at admin/people/permissions#module-restws), and you are sure you have your paths right, you can enable the module's debugging mode:

> ### Debugging
>
> You can enable a debug logging facility by setting a variable in
>   settings.php (e.g. in DRUPAL_ROOT/sites/default/settings.php):
>
> $conf['restws_debug_log'] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/restws_debug.log';
>
> It will write the details of every web service request to the file you
>   have specified, e.g. to DRUPAL_ROOT/restws_debug.log.

(from [README.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/restws/tree/README.txt))

This may provide you with enough more information about what's happening to resolve the issue.